# How did Anakin and Obi-Wan intend to rescue Chancellor Palpatine?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

In *Revenge of the Sith*, according to the title crawl, Anakin and Obi-Wan "lead a
desperate mission to rescue the captive Chancellor." They do this by arriving in two one-man starfighters. Grievous' flagship appears to only hold droid fighters, so they couldn't have stolen other ships once there, and they probably didn't originally intend to crash-land the entire flagship. Do any sources explain how they originally planned to get Palpatine off of the ship?

Comment: "Wait a minute. How did this happen? We're smarter than this." - Obi-Wan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_%28novel%29) covers this. They were hoping to secure a shuttle in the Hangar bay.

> Anakin slewed his starfighter into a landing that scattered droids
>   with the particle blast from his sublight thrusters and for one second
>   he was nine years old again, behind the controls of a starfighter in
>   the Theed royal hangar, his first touch of a real ship’s real cannons
>   blasting battle droids - **He’d have done the same right here, except that
>   Palpatine was somewhere on this ship. They just might need one of the
>   light shuttles in this hangar to get the Chancellor safely to the
>   surface; a few dozen cannon blasts bouncing around in here could wreck
>   them all.**
>
> This he’d have to do by hand.

And assuming that plan failed (which it did), they had a backup;

> “This is not the best plan we’ve ever had!” he shouted. “This was a
>   plan?” Palpatine sounded appalled.
>
> “We’ll make our way forward!” Obi-Wan shouted. “There are only droids
>   back here! **Once we hit live-crew areas, there will be escape pods!**”

Comment: As we witness in The Clone Wars episodes, Obi-Wan & Anakin are somewhat famous for making things up as they go.

Comment: @Omegacron - I think you mean "trusting the Force"...

Comment: Indeed. Those two seem to "trust the Force" waaaay more than the average Jedi. Especially Anakin.

Comment: @omegacron - A habit they picked up from Qui-Gon.

Comment: True. Qui-Gon was a leaf on the wind.

Comment: @Omegacron Watch how he soars?

Comment: @KSmarts - he soared, all right... right onto Maul's lightsaber blade.

Comment: @Omegacron too soon...