# How did Kenobi plan to bring Jango Fett to Coruscant?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

When Obi-wan Kenobi tells Yoda about Jango Fett, Yoda says:

> Bring him here. Question him, we will.

As [this HISHE SW:AoC video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cxjlN9e9-c&t=2m20s) points out, Obi-wan's Jedi Starfighter has *only one seat*. Was he going to stuff Jango Fett in the trunk/spare parts compartment in the back of the ship?

**How did Kenobi plan to bring Jango Fett to Coruscant?**

Comment: Good point; I'd never actually considered that!  +1

Comment: Neither the original, nor Disney Junior novelization offer any detail of how he was supposed to do it. Does that satisfy you as an answer?

Comment: @DVK if an answer addresses the available canon/legends info (or lack thereof) _and then goes on to say_ what they think might've been Kenobi's plan, I'd say that's a decent answer.

Comment: I mean it does have 1 seat, they could just...(¬‿¬)

Comment: Why not just use Fett's ship?

Comment: @Peter - because someone like Fett made sure random weirdos don't succeed at flying his ship without his say-so. EU explicitly covererd that with Boba Fett and some yahoo trying to ship-jack him.

Comment: @DVK I reckon a Jedi might be able to defeat a car alarm ... (also this is Jango, not Boba)

Comment: @Peter - Boba Fett's ship was IIRC the same ship Jango owned in AoC.

Comment: @DVK Who's to say that Boba didn't prevent a ship-jacking because Jango lost his ship to a Jedi? ;)

Comment: If he has some way to keep Jango unconscious for the trip, and he doesn't need to do any fancy flying to return to Coruscant, then it would probably be feasible to just have Jango's unconscious body sitting in his lap for the return voyage, or if the seat is adjustable maybe there'd be room to movie it forward and stuff Jango behind it.

Comment: This seems to be a recurring theme for Obi-Wan: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76893/how-did-anakin-and-obi-wan-intend-to-rescue-chancellor-palpatine

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Neither the film, nor either of the novelizations address this.

However, Obi-Wan planned to contact the Jedi Council **after arresting** Fett, so presumably they could discuss transportation at that point. Doing so prior to actually arresting him would be a wee bit premature, as the events showed.

From the film:

> Yes, Master. **I will report back when I have him**.

From R. A. Salvatore's novelization:

> “Into custody, take this Jango Fett,” Yoda instructed. “Bring him here. Question him, we will.”
>   “Yes, Master. **I will report back when I have him**.” Obi-Wan glanced over his shoulder again and abruptly instructed R4 to cut the transmission.

From Patricia C. Wrede's Disney Junior Novelization:

> Important, this clone army was, certainly; but also a distraction. Yoda frowned. How to reconcile the two? “Into custody, take this Jango Fett,” he told Obi-Wan at last. “Bring him here. Question him, we will.”
>   “Yes, Master,” Obi-Wan said. “**I will report back when I have him**.”

Had he succeeded in capturing Jango, Kenobi would have contacted Yoda to discuss how to bring Jango to Coruscant. We can *speculate* that the Jedi would send a transport, or maybe Kenobi would use either Jango's ship or borrow a ship from the Kaminoans.

Comment: It's interesting to note that we don't know *exactly* who Yoda was referring to when he said "Bring him here" as you could see that as a direct command to Kenobi, or pair it with the next sentence as meaning "Bring him here AND question him, we will" (referring to the Council performing both actions: the transport and questioning). I cannot tell the exact meaning behind it, given Yoda's typical sentence structure.

Comment: Pfft. Who reads the junior novelisations?

Comment: @Richard - Juniors?

Comment: @DVK - Touché, sir.

Comment: @Richard - wanna bet if you do market research, 90% will be overage nerds? :)

Comment: "they could discuss transportation [afterward]". Care to elaborate? I'm fine with speculation.

Comment: @RedCaio - "Hey, Yoda! I captured Jango as ordered and calling in as we agreed. What do you want me to do with him? Take him to Jedi on Coruscant? Sure! Send me a police van, or at least a ship with >1 seat!"