# How could the fireships in RotS know that Grievous' flagship was crewed by friendlies?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

In *Revenge of the Sith*, Anakin and Obi-Wan land on general Grievous' flagship and after some time find themselves at the controls of it with all the bad guys having abandoned ship. They decide to attempt to land on Coruscant and, when approaching the runway, are not only not fired at but even met by fireships that escort them and put out some fires raging on their ship.

How could the fireships, or anyone on the ground for that matter, have known that Grievous' flagship was crewed or at least steered by friendlies? We even see one of the fireship pilots radioing "We'll take you in.", implying he knows who he's talking to. According to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76893/how-did-anakin-and-obi-wan-intend-to-rescue-chancellor-palpatine) it was not the initial plan to take over the flagship so they could not have been informed in advance.

Is it just implied that maybe R2 made an emergency call?

**EDIT:**

The answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110465/why-were-the-the-fireships-trying-to-put-out-the-fires-on-the-invisible-hand) further extends on the topic.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Interestingly, there's a slight discrepancy between the Official Junior Novel and Official Film Novelisation. In the former, it's Anakin who contacts the Clone troops flying alongside. In the latter, it's Kenobi and only after the ship is targeted (and shot at) by Republic fighters:

---

From the film's [Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization)):

> Distantly, he was aware of Obi-Wan and Palpatine following his
> instructions, of R2-D2 taking up a position at the auxiliary controls,
> but his fingers were already busy with the unfamiliar controls. *First,
> stop the shooting. This switch? No … There.* Quickly, he tapped out a
> message to the Republic’s clone fighters: *General Kenobi and I have
> taken the ship. The Chancellor is safe. Stop firing.* He signed it with
> his name and the code that would mark it as an authentic message, and
> sent it off.

and the film's [Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel))

> The cruiser bounced even harder, and its attitude began to skew as a new klaxon joined the blare of the other alarms. “That wasn’t me!” Anakin jerked his hands away from the board. “I haven’t even done anything yet!”
>
> “It certainly wasn’t.” Palpatine’s voice was unnaturally calm. “It seems someone is shooting at us.”
>
> “Wonderful,” Anakin muttered. “Could this day get any better?”

... [shortly afterwards]

> “Perhaps we can talk with them.” Obi-Wan moved over to the comm station and began working the screen. “Let them know we’ve captured the ship.”
>
> “All right, take the comm,” Anakin said. He pointed at the copilot’s station. “Artoo: second chair. Chancellor?”
>
> “You have to stand down the surface-defense system, sir! It’s General Kenobi!” Needa insisted. “His code verifies, Skywalker is with him-and they have Chancellor Palpatine!”
>
> “Heard and understood this is,” the Jedi [Yoda] responded calmly.

Comment: Thanks, so it's just something they didn't care to explain in the movie. Now that I see your answer, an additional question comes to mind though: why was Grievous' ship attacked in the first place if they knew Palpatine was aboard it?

Comment: @user35915 - That's a good next question for you to ask.

Comment: Will do that :-).

Answer (score 23):

Ever proposing alternative theories...

Does the crew of the fireship CARE whose flying the ship? You have a multi-thousand/hundred/(trillion?) ton vessel, burning, full of volatile fuel and ammo, about to crash into a planet that is literally nothing but one massive city.

Regardless of who is on the ship, they are going to try to help direct to a (relatively) safe landing location, while preventing it from exploding violently all over the sky.

---

It's been suggested that the droids on the ship pose a great 
threat then the ship exploding does, so let's look at some rough numbers.

[Coruscant allegedly has the same orbital patterns as Earth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coruscant), so for simplicity sake we're going to treat is as a similar size (say, [510.1 trillion square meters](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=surface%20area%20of%20the%20eart%20in%20meters)). Coruscant also has > 1 trillion citizens, divided by the surface area of earth, we end up with about (I'm rounding generously here) 500 people per square meter. Now, this is an inaccurate number because of things like Poles and Oceans and sky ways (which are likely less densely packed then the buildings).

[A Nuclear Bomb has a 50% survivability rating at 8 KM](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=blast%20radius%20of%20a%20nuclear%20bomb). We'll halve that, to 4 KM, just for fun, [which comes out to 4000000m²](http://www.metric-conversions.org/area/square-kilometers-to-square-meters.htm) x Population Density of 500 for a grand total of 2,000,000,000 people dead. And taking half of that number again, out to 8km for a whopping total of around 3,000,000,000 dead people if the ship explodes with the same force as a nuclear bomb.

The *Invisible Hand* carries 1.5 million battle droids, 3,000,000,000 / 1,500,000 = 2. Each battle droid would have to kill 2000 people before being destroyed. Given both their (limited) combat capabilities and their frailness, this seems highly unlikely.

And, in order to achieve this feat, we can go back to the original population density numbers: They would still have to exterminate every living soul within 4 KM of the crash site to accomplish this. It is highly unlikely they would be able to accomplish this before enough military forces were mobilized against them to stop them.

But let's assume it is within the realm of possibility - wouldn't it STILL be better for the ship to land somewhere, you know, with a big wide open area around it, with no cover for the battle droids, so you could easily pick them off as they are disgorging from the ship?

Sort of like they do, in the movie?

This is in fact [exactly what Spitfire pilots in World War II did](http://americandigest.org/sidelines/2013/10/spitfire_tippin.html) with the buzz bombs that were striking England, tipping them over the countryside or the channel so they would fall out of the sky and crash, and kill less people and cause less damage then if they continued to the target and exploded.

Comment: Good point. It's what firefighters, paramedics, etc. do: save lives first, ask questions later.

Comment: Great point +1. Plus, the Republic seems to have known ahead of time that the Chancellor was on that particular ship -- they'd be trying to save the ship to save him whether they knew it was controlled by the Jedi or not.

Comment: Given that the ship is (they think) full of unfriendly robots, it would be better for it to crash and burn than land safely and disgorge its murderous cargo, surely? Note that a few minutes earlier, the fighters were trying to do just that. Even in wartime, you wouldn't find a fireman trying to make it easier for invasion craft to land without casualties!

Comment: @Richard I've gone ahead to disprove your theory with an edit to my answer, I hope you enjoy it.

Comment: @mark - It lands where it lands because (despite all evidence to the contrary in the film, where the ship basically looks like a huge lump of crap), Anakin is *steering* it. That's why it lands at the airstrip and doesn't plough into the ground. By the same token, the fighters are still firing on the ship *as it makes efforts to right itself*. Clearly they want it to crash.

Comment: @Richard They fire on it while it's still in space, because they want it out of the fight. None of them want it to plow into the surface of Coruscant. But regardless of who is flying it, there are just not going to be that many places a partially disabled and crashing ship is going to be able to set down with a relatively intact cargo on Coruscant, and it's to the fireships and the planets gain to help the ship get there, regardless of who is responsible for steering it.

Comment: @Mark - I feel like this is worthy of a separate question. Not least because I've just found a book quote that proves you wrong :-P

Comment: @Richard So what you're saying is, if they didn't know the chancellor was on board, they were content to just let a multi-ton ship crash into the planet? At this point it was already inside the defenses of the planet, if the Chancellor had made it to an escape pod...then what? Let it crash, let it burn, let it start a bunch of fires? Even the Republic isn't that callous, certainly not about it's capital planet. Did they know? Yes. Did it matter once the ship was going to crash into the planet? No, the fireships would do everything in their power to mitigate the damage. It's their job.

Comment: [Why were the the fireships trying to put out the fires on the Invisible Hand?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110465/why-were-the-the-fireships-trying-to-put-out-the-fires-on-the-invisible-hand)

Comment: @T.J.L. Technically, since Coruscant was invented by Timothy Zahn, I think it would be his fault? Also this is an interesting list for comparison: http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/EN.POP.DNST It shows Hong Kong (which reminds me alot of Coruscant, come to think of it) as having a populating density of 6,700....though that is by KM not M.

Comment: @T.J.L. - It's worth noting that the city extended downwards several kilometers.

Comment: @Mark Your nuclear blast quote indicates radius, a circle. Your 4 km radius circle has an area of approximately 50 square kilometers. You're still having problems with unit conversions and area math. Your "4000000m²" is only 4 square kilometers. Frankly, you should sit down and redo all the math, starting from scratch. Write it down on paper if you have to. You should also pick a larger unit; I suggest kilometers, not meters - doing math for an entire planet in meters is akin to doing math for a city in inches.

Comment: @T.J.L. You are correct that it is a square and not a circle, in my numbers, and that in fact this would actually be closer to a 2 KM circle then a 4 KM circle, but that only increases the numbers of people affected, and the math as it stands, is sufficient to support the conclusion in my answer.

Comment: DVK's answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110480/20774) would strongly indicate that the fireships were **not** being tasked to deal with falling enemy ships. Those were left to the capital's turbolasers and point-defence systems with fighters picking off the larger bits.

Comment: There's something wrong with your arithmetic. If Coruscant is 510 trillion square metres with a population of 1 trillion, that's 500 square metres per person, not 500 people per square metre. Bit of a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just to build a little on the other answers.
I recall this two line exchange in the movie as being the only communication from the ship after our heroes (And the Chancellor and Anakin) take control (control being a loosely applied term):

> Fireship Pilot: "We'll take you in."
>
> Obi-Wan: "Copy that."