# Why were the fireships trying to put out the fires on the Invisible Hand?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Thanks to this question ([How could the fireships in RotS know that Grievous' flagship was crewed by friendlies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110395/how-could-the-fireships-in-rots-know-that-grievous-flagship-was-crewed-by-frien)) we've learned that the [fireships (firefighting speeders)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Emergency_firespeeder) knew that the *Invisible Hand* had been taken over by Anakin Skywalker and Ben Kenobi because they sent a message. But why were they there in the first place?

**Is there any evidence to suggest that they were dousing *all* the ships that were crash-landing (be they friend *or* foe) to prevent casualties on the ground?**

[image: The Invisible Hand coming to land with the fireships beside it]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Non-junior novelization (Matthew Stover's) of ROTJ has this to say:

1. They were there **because debris from earlier battle started tons of fires**.

   > The dayside surface of the capital planet was shrouded in
   >   smoke from a million fires touched off by meteorite impacts of
   >   ship fragments; **far too many had fallen to be tracked and destroyed
   >   by the planet's surface-defense umbrella**.
   >
   > **The nightside's sheet of
   >   artificial lights faded behind the red-white glow from craters of
   >   burning steel; each impact left a caldera of unimaginable death**. In
   >   the skies of Coruscant now, **the important vessels were no longer
   >   warships, but were instead the fire-suppression and rescue craft
   >   that crisscrossed the planet**.
2. Note the first bolded statement in the first paragraph.

   **There's no suggestion that fireships were trying to put out fires on other descending fragments before, as the only approach listed was to destroy them via planet's defenses.**

   This is confirmed because the first response to Invisible Hand's descent was ALSO via Surface Defense attack, until they learned it was Jedi and Sith:

   > Now one last fragmentary ship screamed into the atmosphere, coming in too fast, too steep, pieces breaking off to
   >   spread apart and stream their own contrails of superheated vapor;
   >   **banks of turbolasers on the surface-defense towers isolated their
   >   signature, and starfighters whipped onto interception courses to
   >   thin out whatever fragments the SD towers might miss**, and far
   >   above, beyond the atmosphere, on the bridge of RSS Integrity,
   >   Lieutenant Commander Lorth Needa spoke urgently to a kneehigh blue ghost scanned into existence by the phased-array lasers in
   >   a holocomm: an alien in Jedi robes, with bulging eyes set in a
   >   wrinkled face and long, pointed, oddly flexible ears.
   >   "**You have to stand down the surface-defense system, sir! It's
   >   General Kenobi!" Needa insisted. "His code verifies, Skywalker is
   >   with him — and they have Chancellor Palpatine!**"

   They only think of fireships after getting the idea that they needed to **save** the ship" (e.g. fireships weren't there to prevent ground fires by extinguishing burning debris in flight):

   > "**First, a flight of fireships**," Needa said, more calmly now. "If
   >   they don't get the burnoff under control, there won't be enough
   >   hull left to make the surface.

Comment: Great answer! Linked it in my question.